# Synonyms with concepts that have spaces, or are multiple words

Tags: solr

I don't know how to deal with synonyms which contains a space!
I have the following config:

The SOLR config file

```
<fieldType ... >
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
                            catenateWords="1" 
                            preserveOriginal="1"
                            splitOnCaseChange="1"
                            generateWordParts="1" 
                            generateNumberParts="1"         
                            catenateNumbers="1" 
                            catenateAll="1" 
                            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="30" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">    
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="70" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="syn.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

My file: syn.txt

```
st., st => saint
istambul => istanbul
airport, apt => aéroport
NYC => New York
pt., pt => port
brussels => bruxelles
```

Everything was working fine except the synonym:

```
"NYC => New York"
```

I did some research and I found the following:

> Keep in mind that while the SynonymFilter will happily work with synonyms containing multiple words (ie: "sea biscuit, sea biscit, seabiscuit")
>
> The recommended approach for dealing with synonyms like this, is to expand the synonym when indexing. This is because there are two potential issues that can arise at query time:
>
> The Lucene QueryParser tokenizes on white space before giving any text to the Analyzer, so if a person searches for the words sea biscit the analyzer will be given the words "sea" and "biscit" separately, and will not know that they match a synonym.
>
> Phrase searching (ie: "sea biscit") will cause the QueryParser to pass the entire string to the analyzer, but if the SynonymFilter is configured to expand the synonyms, then when the QueryParser gets the resulting list of tokens back from the Analyzer, it will construct a MultiPhraseQuery that will not have the desired effect.
>
> This is because of the limited mechanism available for the Analyzer to indicate that two terms occupy the same position: there is no way to indicate that a "phrase" occupies the same position as a term.
>
> For our example the resulting MultiPhraseQuery would be "(sea | sea | seabiscuit) (biscuit | biscit)" which would not match the simple case of "seabiscuit" occuring in a document

So I tried to changed my config file and to add my filters at the indexing but it is not working.

Did someone have any ideas?

Comment: Beware of this problem in Solr with multiword synonyms: http://www.opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/10/27/why-is-multi-term-synonyms-so-hard-in-solr/

Answer (score 8):

You are doing explicit mapping with `=>`.

The [Solr documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) says

> Explicit mappings match any token sequence on the LHS of "=>" and *replace* with all alternatives on the RHS.  These types of mappings ignore the expand parameter in the schema.

So I am guessing that if you search for `NYC` you get nothing back, since it got replaced with `New York` at index time.

Instead, can you try declaring them as equivalent synonyms? i.e. like 
`NYC, New York` instead of `NYC => New York`.

Then I believe you can search for either of them and the result will be the same.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that solr synonyms tend to cause issues when the number of words in the first phrase is less than the number of words in the second phrase. When this happens, tokens overflow into the positions of other tokens.

**I have a workaround for this problem**, but it requires two uses of **solr.SynonymFilterFactory** at index and query time.

Like this :

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="multi_word_conversion.txt" 
ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />

<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="layor_two_syns.txt" 
ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
```

In the first filter you will have: New York => New_York

In the second filter: NYC => New_York

Now a search for New York will return results containing NYC and vice verses.

On a final note: **This will method will not work unless it is at index and query time.**

Comment: Then if you have 'New York' somewhere in your index it will never be found when typing 'new' or 'york'

Comment: I agree with dzezzz. Why can't you just do NYC => NYC New York?

Answer (score 2):

About

```
st., st => saint
```

I think you should do it that way :

```
st. => saint
st => saint
```

About

```
NY => New York
```

I'm facing a similar issue and came to the conclusion that it's because parsing is done BEFORE synonym replacement, which is likely causing a problem when multi word.
I found that it is possible to include a parser into SynonymFactory :

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
```

I just tested it I got much better results, but not yet the one expected.
Strangely enough, when adding KeywordTokenizerFactory seems to impact positvely, adding WhitespaceTokenizerFactory or StandardTokenizerFactory doesn't seem to change anything.

BTW, if not using shingles, this should already be fine.

Answer (score 0):

basing on Pr Shadoko's answer:

Look the way your analyzer works, e.g. with

```
http://localhost/solr/analysis/field?analysis.fieldvalue=EXAMPLE-KEYWORDS&q=EXAMPLE-KEYWORD%203&analysis.fieldname=EXAMPLEFIELD&analysis.showmatch=true
```

analysis/field is an out-of-the-box request handler (seated in solrconfig.xml).
[Here](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_3_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/handler/FieldAnalysisRequestHandler.html) you find its parameter list. ("analysis.query" doesn't work for me, so I had to use "q")

As the SynonymFilter parse (cuts) the incoming text BEFORE matching any synonym, the multi-word synonyms won't get a hit.
The trick is to tell the SynonymFilter to take a parser, which actually doesn't parse: the keywordTokenizer

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
```

Anyhow, this approach feels like a hack and I can't estimate the side-effects (scalability, ...) - so be careful!